# Debug vs Release: One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined

Tags: macos, qt4, macports, vtk

I have a problem, quite some time now.

The system settings are OSX Lion with *Xcode 4.2.1*, MacPorts installed *qt4-mac 4.7.4 +debug* and and *vtk5 5.6.1*. I use cmake as build system. The project contains a Qt gui application with a vtk widget. Compiling the gui in debug mode and running it throws a lot of lines like

```
Class QCocoaColorPanelDelegate is implemented in both /opt/local/lib/libQtGui.4.dylib and /opt/local/lib/libQtGui_debug.4.dylib. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
```

with several Cocoa or NS related classes.

otool -L tells me the executable is linked against the qt debug libraries.

Has anyone an idea what causes this and how I could resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
sudo port deactivate qt4-mac-devel +debug
sudo port activate qt4-mac-devel @4.8.0_0+quartz
```

Answer (score 0):

`QCocoaColorPanelDelegate` is implemented in both libraries, but only one of the implementations will be loaded and used. You should probably just link to one library or the other (I'd assume you don't want to link to the debug library).

Comment: This is exactly my problem. I'm trying to debug my program, so I want the debug variants of the library, but for some reason it mixes up.

Comment: If I look at the output of otool -L it shows me libQt*_debug.dylib. I have no idea where the release libraries come from.